# How to perform nested queries in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Model A has_many model_bs.

Model B belongs_to model_a and model_c.

Model C has_many model_bs and can by of type `black` or `white`.

I want to pull all records of model A, which have model Bs, that belong to model C of type `black`. So far I could pull all records of model B, which belong to model C of type `black`, like so:

```
ModelB.joins(:model_c).where("model_c.type = 'black'")
```

This returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_ModelB`, but now I need something like:

```
records = ModelB.joins(:model_c).where("model_c.type = 'black'")
Model_A.where model_b: records
```

which doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Another thing I tried was:

```
Model_A.includes(:model_bs).includes(model_c).where("model_c.type = 'black'")
```

but this produces the error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError:
       Association named 'model_c' was not found on ModelA; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

So how do I do this? I would also like to understand the principle of querying, when you have a lot of chained models and want to retrieve records of model X, based on attribute of model Y, with model Y being n levels away from model X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `joins` and not `includes` since you only want one model as a result.

```
Model_A.joins(model_bs: :model_c).where("model_cs.type = 'black'").references(:model_cs)
```

because modelA has many modelbs
and modelC has many modelbs

Comment: Yes, this works, however, please edit `:model_bs => :model_cs` to `:model_bs => :model_c`, since model_b belongs_to one model_c.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo: `includes(model_c)` should be `includes(:model_c)` and this is where the error `Association named 'model_c' was not found on ModelA` came from.

One way to get your query could be:

```
Model_A.includes(:model_bs, :model_cs).where("model_cs.type = 'black'").references(:model_cs)
```

---

Also in your models you could link Model_A and Model_C directly by:

In Model_A

```
has_many :model_cs, :through => :model_bs
```

In Model_C

```
has_many :model_as, : through => :model_bs
```

Comment: While I did made a mistake in my original post, I hadn't made this mistake in the query so that was not the problem. The query suggested by you also produces the same error. I think the error stems from the fact that Model A and Model C have no relation and hence the error "Association named 'model_c' was not found on ModelA;"

Comment: I changed my query to includes :model_cs, since it's a has_many relationship. Try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record - since I constantly got the error that no model_c attribute is defined on ModelA I figured that in `ModelA.includes(:model_bs).includes(:model_c)` it searches for a direct relation between ModelA and ModelC. So I did this - the common entity between ModelA and ModelC is ModelB, thus:

```
ModelB.includes(:model_a).included(:model_c).where("my_string_criteria")
```

Although this returns instances of ModelB and not of ModelA, as I originally wanted, this was not a problem, as I only needed the values from one field of ModelA and was going to use `pluck` anyway. So I used `pluck` on the above mentioned relation instead and still got what I was looking for. But [xlembouras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23651172/1836143) was more precise and more efficient so I went with his suggestion.